# Specific Case of Independence Between Training Examples

Tags: modeling, independence

I have a training dataset in which each example represents a product order and a binary label which indicates if that order turned out to be out of stock.  The goal is to train a model that predicts whether an order will be out-of-stock.  Also, in terms of input features, I only have access to information prior to the day it was determined to be out of stock i.e. no information about the day itself.

My question is about whether the examples in the dataset are independent.  For example, there may have been an order for "product A" that was found to be in stock in the morning but may have been the last one thus making the next order for "product A" during that same day be out of stock.  So in this way one training example could depend on another training example.  Also, in a case like this, since I don't have access to information about the day itself, the information for both orders would be the exact same and therefore the predictions would be the exact same which would mean that either way one prediction would be wrong.

Is there a name for this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your training data is randomly selected, or consists of all the records, then your sampling method is independent. You aren't selecting records based on the values of other records, which would violate independence.  Variables interacting or correlating is a separate issue from independent sampling.

Comment: Yes it is the interaction between examples that is concerning me